# Flash hides behind submenu, z-index is not working

Tags: html, flash

actually i have an image gallery in a seperate HTML page, I want to embed it into the main html page containing the menu, but even after using the code `<param name="wmode" value="transparent">` or `<param name="wmode" value="opaque">` the submenu is still hiding behind the flash. I also tried by changing z-index values, still didn't work. Any ideas on what else I could try?

Comment: Can you post a link. More times than not it is a problem with the param wmode needing to be transparent

Answer (score 3):

Try set the WMODE parameter to TRANSPARENT.

That is, in the  element, place this:

```
<PARAM NAME="WMODE" VALUE="transparent">
```

And add also the this attribute to :

```
WMODE=transparent
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `wmode` on the `embed object` to `transparent` as well as the `param wmode`.

`<embed ... wmode="transparent"...`

AND

`<param name="wmode" value="transparent">`

I would also recommend using swfobject. It'll make your life easier with issues as such

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation